# Integrated Gradients Error - Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: nlp, gradient, bert-language-model

I am new to transformers, but I managed to create a Bert classifier using tensorflow and now I want to implement Integreted Gradients to explain the model, ,but I get this error:

> Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

If you think that you can help, please find my code here: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18imP8yxpuenwWFGzdYQ1sWejRJd1vbOy?authuser=1#scrollTo=Le2Sl2QP_KSO) because it is a lot of code to paste in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your notebook, the error is triggered by

```
explanation = ig.explain(a,
                         baselines=None,
                         target=predictions)
```

Therefore, it seems that `ig` requires non-empty baselines.